# sql query & foreach and <td>

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to get auctions info and put into  so to do this i think i need have result in string not in array and i do next

```
         $aUserData = DBC::$slave->selectAssoc(" 
     SELECT 
    s.id_auction                           AS _key_,
    s.id_auction                           AS id,
    s.seller_user_name                         AS user_name,
    s.end_date_time                        AS finish_date,
    s.suspended                            AS active,
    s.id_category                          AS category,
    s.title                            AS title
    FROM auctions_search                       AS s
    WHERE TRUE
    AND s.status        = 'active'
    AND s.suspended         = 'no'
    ");
        foreach ($aUserData as $iKey => $nUserID)
     {
     if (!isset($aUserData[$nUserID]))continue; 

     }
                 $nUserID = implode(',',$nUserID);

     Tools::printPre($nUserID);
```

and result is  `string(80) "150031,u0001,2013-08-19 16:08:03,no,833,Title of Item"

but here show only 1 result since in sql query i have multiple result for multiple users

after geting result i need go and foreach `<tr><td>ID of AUCTION:(put here ID of item)</td></tr>Title:(title of item) and etc`

any ideas?

Comment: Which SQL are you using? To which object/class does `selectAssoc()` belong?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance,  but I still can't find a `selectAssoc()` method anywhere. Is it part of some PEAR package? I have so far only worked with `mysql(i)_*` functions ... Without knowing what `selectAssoc()` returns it is difficult to find a fix.

Comment: sorry to didnt define it , its from our site framework , its mean we have select query with _key_ :) , if under sellectAssoc() i enter a query without key will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said

> we have select query with key :) , if under sellectAssoc() i enter a
>   query without key will not work

If you really only get one record back from that query you will have to *either* modify you query so you get multiple records at once *or* do the query several times.

For each record you can then use the following to fill a single table row:

```
foreach ($aUserData as $iKey => $nUserID){ // for each record found ...
  $str="<tr id='$iKey'><td>".join('</td><td>',$nUserId)."</td></tr>";
  Tools::printPre($str); // using your framework to print the line ...
}
```

I left out the captions 'ID of AUCTION:' and 'Title:' in the table cells. They should be used as headings in a separate table row *above* the actual table body like

```
<tr><th>ID of AUCTION</th><th>Title</th> ... </tr>
```

Comment: This is give me a result of what i want but doesnt in TD tags

Comment: Have you looked at the html-source code of the page that was generated? Maybe you can get a clue from there what has gone wrong? A missing `<` or `/` somewhere? And, of course, the whole thing still needs to be wrapped in `<table></table>`! And - another thing - I don't know your `Tools::printPre()`. Maybe this function strips all html-tags from your input string?

Comment: Tools::printPre() = print_R 

 yea missing `<table>`  but when trying to do like
       `$sAuctionContent= "<table>"
              foreach(.... as ...)` 
giving me error

Comment: Hey, you obviously have to add it to the output string. `foreach` is just a loop construct. It does not return anything! Maybe you could try a `Tools::printPre('<table>');` before and a `Tools::printPre('</table>');` after the `foreach` loop?